# Bash scripting and linuxbash

Tags: bash

I hope someone can help me. my question is with a script in bash that receives a certain amount of parameters and then show them in the reverse order of the one.  as I keep name one for each line in the vvariable and then show them around.

```
#!/bin/bash
var=""
for i in "$@";do
     var+=`echo $i`
done
```

Comment: OK, and ... what is the problem you are facing? What is the current output, and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

If you want reversed order, you have to loop in reversed order:

```
for ((i=$#; i>=1;i--)); do
    a=${!i}
    echo "$a"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this would be:

```
echo $@  | rev
```

`$@` stores all the arguments passed, and `rev`, as its name suggests, reverses the order of characters in the line.

Edit:

After reading your comment, I can suggest the following approach:

```
for i in `echo $@ | rev`; do
    j=`echo $i | rev`
    echo -n "$j "
done
```

Comment: The question was not very clear, but I thing reversing the order meant: `foo bar` becomes `bar foo`, not `rab oof`

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it helps !